# How to read google api credentials from json file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-calendar-api

I am reading google api client credentials from json file as follows,

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\sample\client_secret.json"
, FileMode.Open
, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
    "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(@"c:\datastore", true)
    ).Result;
}
```

But is failing to read credentials from server, it is reading finely when checking in my local, Can any one suggest me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the [.Net quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) of the calendar API documentation. It will show you on how to use .net to make request with the Google Calendar API. There is a sample code here that you can follow. For more information, you can also check this [Google Calendar API Authentication with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) tutorial.